# COUNT query in MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by

I have these relations:

`station` (station_id, latitude, longitude) 
`station_control_manager` (station_id, ctrl_unit_id)

Problem

> Tabulate station names, ids and total numbers of control areas in the middle town area, 
>   e.g., latitude between 40.750 and 40.760 and longitude between -74.000 and -73.95.

This is my query

```
SELECT DISTINCT s.station_name, s.station_id, count 
FROM station s, 
   (SELECT cm.station_id, COUNT(cm.station_id) as count
    FROM stationcontrolmanager cm GROUP BY cm.station_id) sub_query
WHERE s.latitude >= 40.750 
  AND s.latitude <=40.760 
  AND s.longitude >= -74.000 
  AND s.longitude <= -73.95 
GROUP BY s.station_id;
```

I count by grouping `station_id` and count how many times it repeats (by repating, we know how many control area it has).

Instead, I have this:
[image]

The count was supposed to be the number of `ctrl_unit_id`, which in this case, is also the number of `station_id`. But in DB I count 7 rows, not 2.

The station names are all correct, of course.

Is there something wrong with my SQL statements?

Comment: You need to tell MySQL how `sub_query` joins to your `station` table: e.g. add `AND s.station_id = sub_query.station_id` to your `WHERE` clause.

Comment: @eggyal You are right about this. But why is it required? I do add the subquery in my other queries. Do you mind to explain when you have time? Thanks.

Comment: Without it, you're performing a full cartesian cross-join between `sub_query` and `station` - that is, there will be a resulting row for every row in `sub_query` joined with every row in `station`.  Read up on [SQL joins](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html).

Comment: @eggyal Thanks. `JOIN` seems to be really useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this without sub-queries:

```
SELECT station.station_id, station_name, COUNT(ctrl_unit_id)
FROM station
LEFT JOIN station_control_manager ON station.station_id = station_control_manager.station_id
WHERE (latitude BETWEEN 40.750 AND 40.760) AND (longitude BETWEEN -74.000 AND -73.95)
GROUP BY station.station_id, station_name
```

1. Since you need information from both tables, you need to join them using `station_id`
2. You need to use `LEFT JOIN` since a station may have zero control managers (RIGHT JOIN will eliminate station records where there is no corresponding control manager record)
3. You need to `COUNT(ctrl_unit_id)` instead of `COUNT(*)` since the latter will (still) return 1 when a station has no control unit associated with it.
4. The `WHERE` clause is self-explanatory

Comment: Thank you very much. It's clear. I am not very familiar with `JOIN`, and I know it's one great tool to use. I like the part you did the total count. I am trying to modify my query so I can report the final count as well.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
SELECT a.station_ID, a.station_name, COUNT(b.station_ID)
FROM station a INNER JOIN station_control_manager b
        on a.station_ID = b.station_ID
WHERE  (a.latitude between 40.75 and 40.76) AND
       (a.longitude between -74.0 and -73.95)
GROUP BY a.station_ID
```

By grouping the records, it is now OK to omit `DISTINCT` keyword.

Comment: Thank you very much. You present a very nice solution as well. I will keep this as a reference. Let me try to modify mine first.